# nose unittest discovery broken on python 3.8

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, nose

Upgraded from python 3.7 to 3.8 today. Unittest discovery in nose no longer works.

Simplified project layout

```
x:\proj\src\__init__.py
x:\proj\src\first.py
x:\proj\tests\__init.py
x:\proj\tests\testfirst.py
```

From project root `x:\proj`, run:

```
nosetests -v
-----------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.016s

OK
```

Can only run unittests by specifying them, eg:

```
nosetests tests.testfirst
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Platform

- nosetests version 1.3.7
- Python 3.8.0 (tags/v3.8.0:fa919fd, Oct 14
  2019, 19:37:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nose now requires you use the `--traverse-namespace` option when there are multiple packages. You can add this to the `nosetests` invocation, or to save yourself typing, add it to `setup.cfg`, eg:

```
[nosetests]
traverse-namespace=1
```

Comment: I can't say whether nose or python is the cause of this, but I can confirm the same behavior. nose successfully finds all tests using Python 3.7 on Windows 10, but fails with Python 3.8 without --traverse-namespace.